# How can I declare an arr1 of ARRAY_SIZE with the appropriate type 64 bit integer

Tags: java

public class Sorting {
    static final String IN_FILE = "sorting.txt";
    static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 20000;

```
static public void main(String[] args) {

   int[] arr1= new int [ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Answer (score 1):

`long` is **64bit**, **signed**, **two's complement** integer.

```
long[] arr1= new long [ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Comment: how would I be able to use a selection sort to sort this array?